# JAVA - SQL SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am creating a method in Java. That is to retrieve messages from the database but I keep getting syntax errors. Can someone help me?

```
public static String retrieveMessages()
{
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    try
    {
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from  tblEmail"
                + "INNERJOIN tblUser "
                +  "ON tblUser.username = tblEmail.`from`"
                +  "WHERE tblUser.username = ?");

        pstmt.setString(1, user.Getuser());
        results = pstmt.executeQuery();

    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (results.toString());

}
```

Comment: @Masud that will compile, that's not the issue.

Comment: "*but I keep getting syntax errors*" how about posting errors you are getting to let people with same errors find answers posted here? This will also improve your chances of getting better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add spaces (before `INNER` and before `WHERE`). Spliting the query to multiple lines doesn't separate the end of one row from the beginning of the next row.

```
    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from  tblEmail "
                                      + "INNER JOIN tblUser "
                                      +  "ON tblUser.username = tblEmail.`from` "
                                      +  "WHERE tblUser.username = ?");
```

When you write:

```
                                        "SELECT * from  tblEmail"
                                      + "INNER JOIN tblUser "
```

It is the same as:

```
                                        "SELECT * from  tblEmailINNER JOIN tblUser "
```

Answer (score 2):

Add space between `tblEmail` and `inner` and  between `from` an `where`

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from  tblEmail "
                                          + "INNER JOIN tblUser "
                                          +  "ON tblUser.username = tblEmail.`from` "
                                          +  "WHERE tblUser.username = ?");
```